# NGINX: using regex from variable

Tags: nginx, cors

I'm trying to implement CORS in my NGINX vhost definition, based on the config from http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html. What I'm trying to achieve is to assign a variable $valid_cors_origin in my vhost definition and then include a different file that handles all the CORS validation, like so:

```
location / {
  ...
  $valid_cors_origin = "foobar";
  include cors_handling;
}
```

while I've stripped the `location` environment from the example from enable-cors.org. In this setup, the following works in `cors_handling`:

```
if ($http_origin = "${valid_cors_origin}"){
  set $cors "true";
}
```

as long as I add the `Origin: foobar` header to my request, obviously.

In the example from enable-cors.org, they're using a regular expression to match against the `$http_origin`. I want to be able to do the same, and therefore need to assign a regular expression to the variable `$valid_cors_origin`. The problem is the variable doesn't seem to be evaluated in the if statement. So far I've tried the following, without any luck:

```
$valid_cors_origin = "/(foo|bar)/";
if ($http_origin *~ $valid_cors_origin){
  set $cors "true";
}
```

leaves me with

```
[notice] 43797#0: *1 $valid_cors_origin does not match "foobar"
```

Trying to force string evaluation:

```
if ($http_origin *~ "${valid_cors_origin}"){
  set $cors "true";
}
[notice] 43797#0: *1 "${valid_cors_origin}" does not match "foobar"
```

And some other variations in which I replaced `$valid_cors_origin` with just `/foo/`, but since it doens't seem to be evaluated, I think it doesn't matter what I assign to `$valid_cors_origin`.

Is this even possible in NGINX, and/or are there other modular ways to solve this problem? Basic requirement: I want to be able to fully manage my valid origins from the vhost file and keep the `cors_handling` config as generic as possible.

**Update**: 
I finally got time to test the proposed solution by @cnst, and it works fine. Just to be complete, I removed the check for $http_origin from the file cors_handling and moved the check to the vhost itself, where I can do this:

```
if ($http_origin ~* (regex|for|my|httporigin)) {
  set $cors "true";
}
include cors_handling;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need an intermediate variable against which you have to compare `$http_origin`?

You could instead directly use the `if` directive as you're doing, and, if needed, place the whole directive into a separate file, and then `include` it in place of where you want the `$http_origin` evaluated.

Or, if you have the whole `cors_handling` already in a separate file, just move the heading `if` (with comparison against `$http_origin`) back to your actual `location` (or even the whole `server`).

You obviously can't do what you're trying to do the same way as you've tried doing, but these alternatives seem quite sufficient and reasonable.

Comment: I could indeed move the check for $http_origin to the location environment, as long as I hardcode $cors to "true" in the enable-cors.org example. I will try that and post my results.